# Displaying ArrayList objects?

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, linked-list

I've got an ArrayList full of LinkedLists and I need to be able to display specific linked lists within that arraylist.

```
        for(int i=0;i<my_lists.size();i++){
        System.out.println(my_lists.get(my_lists.size()));
    }
```

This is displaying in output :

```
kruskal.LinkedList@a4aad7f

kruskal.LinkedList@2cc47220

kruskal.LinkedList@1520a9d6

kruskal.LinkedList@136e2b70

kruskal.LinkedList@25e5d007

kruskal.LinkedList@12bc8f01

kruskal.LinkedList@19509443
```

as my output. Why is it not displaying my Linked Lists?

Here's my LinkedList class:

```
package kruskal;

public class LinkedList {

Node head;

public LinkedList(){
    this.head = null;
}

public void add (Object newData){
    Node cache = head;
    Node current = null;

    if (cache == null)
        current = new Node(newData, null);
        else {


    while ((current = cache.next) != null)
        cache = cache.next;

    cache.next = new Node(newData,null);
        }
}

public Object getFront(){
    return this.head.data;
}

}
```

Comment: What type of objects did the linkList hold?

Comment: because you are printing the elements in the arrayList, which are linkedList so you print each linkedList address, not its elements.

Comment: how does my_lists.get(my_lists.size()) not throw index out of bounds exception?

Comment: A word of advice to the original poster: Let your LinkedList extend java.util.AbstractList, then you'll have a working toString() implementation plus a bunch of other things.

Answer (score 1):

In your code this line `my_lists.get(my_lists.size())` must give you error of because you are reading a object at index `my_lists.size()` which never exist and give error like `Index Out of bounds exception`.
You need to read your LinkedList in loop inside your for loop.

```
for(int i=0;i<my_lists.size();i++){
    LinkedList link = my_lists.get(i)
    //Read value from LinkedList here  
    for(int j=0;j<link.size();j++){    
        //I dont know what type of object stoer in your linked list so i get it in Object
        Object obj = link.get(j);  //read your value here as per data type stored. 
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to like link.size and link.get

Comment: Please provide whole code so that we can find problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since LinkedList is an object, when you print the object using `System.out.println`, the `toString()` method is called. Since your class does not have a `toString()` method, its parent class' `toString()` is called, which in this case is most probably Object.

So you need to override the `toString()` method in your `LinkedList` class and print the object in the way you want.

Comment: Look more closely: The entries start like this: `kruskal.LinkedList` - we're not dealing with the standard LinkedList from the JDK here. :)

Comment: So how do I go about creating a toString method for my linkedlist class?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you haven't overridden the `toString()` method in your `LinkedList` class.

Override `toString()` and have it iterate through the list returning a CSV of the `toString()` values of each element (like the implementation of `java.util.LinkedList`)